# Correct process for performing multiple git remote pushes

Tags: git, version-control, github, versioning, git-svn

My project consists of:

- A git repository stored on bitbucket
- A local copy
- A development copy on a server

On my server, I ran the following command to create a bare repo

```
git init --bare project.git
```

To create the ability to push to my server, I ran the following commands out of the repository on my local machine:

```
git remote add serverrepo username@serverip:/path/to/repo/project.git
git remote set-url serverrepo --push --add username@serverip:/path/to/repo/project.git
```

If I try to push to the server by executing

```
git push serverrepo master
```

I get a

```
fatal: '/path/to/repo/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I've been searching for days, and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What's the output of `ssh username@serverip ls /path/to/repo/project.git`?

Comment: branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs

Comment: Okay, that's a good sign. And it doesn't work if you skip the remote alias and push explicitly push to the URL, i.e. `git push ssh://username@serverip/path/to/repo/project.git master`? While I don't think it matters, take note that the push URL shouldn't contain a colon since you're not specifying a port – see the [URL section of git-push(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#URLS).

Comment: fatal: '/path/to/repo/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the second `git remote` command (the one with `remote set-url serverrepo --push --add`).
You don't need it.

If you already typed that command, make sure to clean every remote entry in your local `.git/config`, and start over.

Simply type:

```
git remote add serverrepo username@serverip:/path/to/repo/project.git
git push -u serverrepo master
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still getting fatal: '/path/to/repo/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository. I can't believe that Git is this difficult to work with!

Comment: It seems like there's something wrong on the side of my remote, right? Do I need to run a different command there?

Comment: @runningonplants yes, considering your remote is accessed by ssh, it needs to be declared with an ssh url: `git remote set-url origin ssh://username@serverip/path/to/repo/project.git`

Comment: Still getting the "does not appear to be a git repository" message. Boy I'm beginning to think this is a lost cause.

Comment: @runningonplants strange, considering `ssh username@serverip ls /path/to/repo/project.git` does work. You are running your push as `username`, right? What does `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for helping me. localrepo   https://bitbucketusername@bitbucket.org/project/project.git (fetch) 
localrepo   https://bitbucketusername@bitbucket.org/project/project.git (push)
serverrepo  username@serverip:/path/to/repo/project.git (fetch)
serverrepo  username@serverip:/path/to/repo/project.git (push)

Comment: @runningonplants wait, '`bitbucketusername@bitbucket.org`' ? It should by '`git@bitbucket.org`': see https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket

Comment: @runningonplants Try `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/bitbucketusername/project.git`, and make sure your key is properly published on your BitBucket account: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git